# ElasticSearch mapping add a not analysed field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to add a raw field not analysed to all the current field.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "dynamic_templates": [{
                "string_fields": {
                    "match": "*",
                    "match_mapping_type": "string",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

But when I reindex, I get the following error message:

> Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Root
>   type mapping not empty after parsing!

Any clue?

Comment: What command did you use when you reindexed? (including the URL)

Comment: I use a python client. http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html But it's not comming from there. I got the same error with $ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}'

Comment: Works for me. Must be something with the mapping... Can you post the output of `GET /twitter/tweet/_mapping` ?

Comment: It does not work with the creation of a new index. If the index is already created, it has no impact.

Comment: Right. The twitter index is created, or it fails?

Comment: If the index is not created, it fails. If the index is already created, (meaning there is already a tweet), it has no impact, the other tweets are indexed the same way.

Comment: Are there any steps I can use to recreate the issue? What you have provided until now works for me.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79271/discussion-between-user2409399-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: It does work when adding the mapping with the PUT/POST API but not when creating a json config file.

Comment: That error is usually seen when there is a mistake in the command.